# Adding Cordova 6.1.1 Project to Android 4.4.2 version

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I am using Cordova 6.1.1 version and Android 4.4.2 version. When I am adding the cordova project in Eclipse, it is giving the error in properties like "cordovalib.jar" is missing in bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following steps:

- Refresh the project
- Disable auto build
- Clean the project
- Exit Eclipse
- Restart Eclipse
- Built project again

Looks like a common [eclipse error](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8704)